# How to make minted NFT NOT show up on any marketplace?

Tags: nft, smart-contract-wallets, opensea, mint

I'm curious if its possible to mint an NFT and make it NOT automatically show up on OpeanSea/Rarible/etc.

Tried googling a lot, but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question.

Marketplaces probably watch for contract deployments and check whether the new contract is of NFT type. Then they use its standard functions to get its data.

A few (dumb or very dumb) ideas come to my mind:

1. Add functionality which gives wrong/bad data upon request until the owner sets some flag and it starts showing right data. If the initial data is incorrect enough, the marketplaces probably won't list the NFT
2. Don't implement all of the NFT's standard functionality. This will lead into weird stuff happening in third party services (if they even list the contract)
3. Add some sort of spatial changes in the contract, so that image changes once  a week for example. This possibly won't stop if from being listed, but again, weird stuff will happen

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about things in a similar way. But, like you said, this would lead to potentially funny behaviour in the later stages and it is not feasible. Maybe somehow blacklisting certain addresses (even though this is also not a solution)?